# Update no sqlite nao atualiza dados

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Olá, alguém poderia me auxiliar ,o update não esta atualizando os dados!

Segue o botão que chama o método:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        Receita rec = new Receita();
        String dosradio = null;
        switch(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
        case R.id.rbCmp:
            dosradio = "cmp";
            break;
        case R.id.rbMl:
            dosradio = "ml";
            break;

        }
         if (getIntent().getExtras() == null){

        rec.setMedicamento(txtMedi.getText().toString());
        rec.setDosagem(txtDos.getText().toString());
        rec.setHorario(spn1.getSelectedItem().toString());
        rec.setVencimento(txtDt.getText().toString());
        rec.setdosradio(dosradio.toString());
        bdhelper.insertRec(rec);
         }
         else{

             rec.setMedicamento(txtMedi.getText().toString());
                rec.setDosagem(txtDos.getText().toString());
                rec.setHorario(spn1.getSelectedItem().toString());
                rec.setVencimento(txtDt.getText().toString());
                rec.setdosradio(dosradio.toString());
                bdhelper.updateReceita(rec);

         }

     }

        public void updateReceita(Receita rec) 
       {
          db = getWritableDatabase();
          ContentValues editContact = new ContentValues();
          editContact.put("medicamento", rec.getMedicamento());
          editContact.put("dosagem", rec.getDosagem());
          editContact.put("dosradio", rec.getdosRadio());
          editContact.put("horario", rec.getHorario());
          editContact.put("venciment", rec.getVencimento());

          db.update("tab", editContact, "_id=" + rec.getId(), null);
          db.close();
       } //
```

Comment: @ThiagoRiderAugusto suas edições não estão melhorando o entendimento da pergunta(que por sinal não está muito clara por si). Por esta razão rejeitei suas edições.

Comment: Matheus, sua pergunta está um pouco confusa, edite-a explicando melhor o problema enfrentado.

Comment: Poderia adicionar o método **updateReceita** ?? É lá que ñ está funcionando, correto?

Comment: ok editei a Pergunta

Comment: problema resolvido...obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Tente realizar o update da seguinte forma:

```
db.update("tab", editContact, "_id = ?", new String[]{rec.getId().toString()});
db.close();
```

Você pode incluir `?` na cláusula `WHERE`, que será substituído pelos valores do quarto parametro.

Os valores serão vinculados como `String`.

[Segue a documentação.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))